# Using Wilson's Theorem to show a particular congruence holds.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to answer the following: Does the congruence $x^2 \equiv -1$ (mod $p$) have any solutions if $p \equiv 3$ (mod $4$)? If so, how many incongruent solutions does it have? If not, why not?

I know from the previous part of the question that if $p$ is a prime and $p \equiv 1$ (mod $4$), then the congruence $x^2 \equiv -1$ (mod $p$) has two incongruent solutions, namely $x \equiv \pm (\dfrac{p-1}{2})!$ (mod $p$).

I am completely unsure how to even approach solving this problem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $p$ is an odd prime. You know that $$\,p\equiv 1\pmod{\! 4}\,\Rightarrow\, (x^2\equiv -1\pmod{\! p}\,\text{ is solvable})$$ by your constructive proof, namely $x\equiv\pm\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\pmod{\! p}$ works as a solution. Proofs of this have been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275461/elementary-proof-that-1-is-a-square-in-mathbbf-p-for-p-1-mod4).

Now you want to prove it in the other direction, namely $$(x^2\equiv -1\!\pmod{\! p} \,\text{ is solvable})\,\Rightarrow\,p\equiv 1\pmod{\! 4}$$

For two proofs, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1265465/107671) with $(a,b)=(x,1)$, where it's proved that more generally:

$p\nmid a,b$ and $p\mid a^2+b^2$ implies $p\equiv 1\pmod{\! 4}$.

You can show $\iff$ at once by proving Euler's criterion (I try to prove it simply [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1320903/107671), or you can see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799554/a-combinatorial-proof-of-eulers-criterion-tfracap-equiv-a-fracp-1) for combinatorial proofs, in which André Nicolas extends his combinatorial argument in your question to prove a more general statement).

Answer (score 3):

André Nicolas has an approach that uses Wilson's theorem, as requested by the OP, but I guess I'll leave my answer up.

---

No, it has no solutions.  The first step is to observe that, for an odd prime $p$,
$$x^2\equiv -1\bmod p\iff x\text{ has order 4 in }(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$$
But the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic, so
$$\text{there exists an element of order $d$ in }(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times\iff d\text{ divides }\lvert(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times\rvert=p-1$$
Thus, for an odd prime $p$, there exist solutions to $x^2\equiv -1\bmod p$ if and only if $4$ divides $p-1$, i.e., if and only if $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$.

Thus, there are no solutions when $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $(\mathbb{Z}{p\mathbb{Z}})^{x}$. I do know it's supposed to be the integers modulo $p$ a prime but I don't understand what the $x$ super-script is supposed to represent.

Also, how do we know that $x^2 \equiv -1$ mod($p$) $\leftrightarrow$ $x$ has order $4$ in $(\mathbb{Z}{p\mathbb{Z}})^{x}$?

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ (written `(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times`) is the group of units of the integers modulo $p$. In other words, it consists of
$$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times=\{[1],[2],\ldots,[p-1]\}$$
and the group operation is multiplication of residue classes mod $p$. [Here's the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n).

Answer (score 1):

The following is a proof that uses Wilson's Theorem. There are "easier" (and group-theoretically more natural) proofs that do not use Wilson's Theorem. The idea is due to Dirichlet.

Let $p$ be a prime of the form $4k+3$.  We will assume that the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution, and use Wilson's Theorem to derive a contradiction.

If $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ had a solution $c$, then it would have exactly $2$ solutions, namely $c$ and $p-c$.

If $1\le a\le p-1$ and $1\le b\le p-1$, with $a\ne b$, call $a$ and $b$ **buddies** if $ab\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. Apart from $c$ and $p-c$, all numbers $a$ in the interval $1\le a\le p-1$ has a unique buddy $b\ne a$ in the interval $1\le b\le p-1$. So the numbers in the interval are divided into $\frac{p-3}{2}$ pairs of buddies, plus the numbers $c$ and $p-c$.

It follows that 
$$(p-1)!\equiv (-1)^{(p-3)/2}(c)(p-c)\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$$
This contradicts Wilson's Theorem. It follows that there cannot be a $c$ such that $c^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

**Remark:** The OP alluded to a Wilson's Theorem proof of the fact that if $p$ is of the form $4k+1$, then the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution. We give a *different* Wilson's Theorem based proof, that uses the ideas in the answer above.

Suppose to the contrary that $p=4k+1$ and the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution. Then all the numbers from $1$ to $p-1$ are divided into buddy pairs. It follows that $(p-1)!\equiv (-1)^{2k}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, contradicting Wilson's Theorem.